# Entity Framework Core (Code First) won't insert into dependent tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an application (.NET Framework 4.8) that uses Entity Framework Core 3.1.5.
(I haven't dared to upgrade because I feel that this may break other dependencies - I'm glad it's working as it is.)

I am using a "Code First" approach to export data from SharePoint into SQL tables.
Some SharePoint "lists" (SharePoint concept of tables) can contain M:N mappings, which I have to separate out into individual SQL tables.

Some code:

```csharp
    // Base class for all parent tables
    internal abstract class SharePointListModel
    {
        [SharePointColumn("ID")]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual void PostProcess()
        {
        }
    }

    // Base class for all child tables
    internal abstract class AdditionalTableModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    // This is the child table, which is never inserted
    [Table("MyMappingTable", Schema = "myschema")]
    internal class MyMappingTable : AdditionalTableModel
    {
        // This points to a third table, but it could really
        // be any value. It could also be a string or BLOB etc.
        public int OtherTableId { get; set; }
    }

    // This is the parent table, which is inserted correctly
    [Table("MySharePointTable", Schema = "myschema")]
    internal class MySharePointTable : SharePointListModel
    {
        [SharePointColumn("SharePointLookupColumn", UseId = true)]
        [NotMapped]
        public int[] OtherTableIds { get; set; }

        public List<MyMappingTable> Mappings { get; set; } // Making the property virtual doesn't change anything either

        public override void PostProcess()
        {
            Mappings = OtherTableIds?.Select(x => new MyMappingTable { OtherTableId = x }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Entity Framework seems to understand this, as dbContext.CreateTable() creates a table "MyMappingTable" that contains three columns (although only two properties are defined): Id, OtherTableId (actually a foreign key, but EF doesn't know that) **and MySharePointTableId (foreign key)**.

[image: Generated child (mapping) table]

But when I insert data like this, the M:N mapping table (MyMappingTable) remains empty:

```csharp
IList<MySharePointTable> = LoadSharePointTable();
dbContext.AddRange(data);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Explicitly mapping the parent doesn't help either:

```csharp
    [Table("MyMappingTable", Schema = "myschema")]
    internal class MyMappingTable : AdditionalTableModel
    {
        public virtual MySharePointTable Parent { get; set; }
        public int OtherTableId { get; set; }
    }

// [...]
        public override void PostProcess()
        {
            Mappings = OtherTableIds?.Select(x => new MyMappingTable { Parent = this, OtherTableId = x }).ToList();
        }
```

I have also tried explicitly inserting the dependent rows, but that doesn't change anything:

```csharp
IList<MySharePointTable> = LoadSharePointTable();
dbContext.AddRange(data);
IEnumerable<MyMappingTable> dependentRows = data.SelectMany(x => x.Mappings ?? Enumerable.Empty<MyMappingTable>());
dbContext.AddRange(dependentRows);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Or like this, but this also doesn't change anything, the child table remains empty:

```csharp
IList<MySharePointTable> = LoadSharePointTable();
dbContext.AddRange(data);
IEnumerable<MyMappingTable> dependentRows = data.SelectMany(x => x.Mappings ?? Enumerable.Empty<MyMappingTable>());
dbContext.Set<MyMappingTable>().AddRange(dependentRows);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The insertion code is slightly simplified here as I'm actually using reflection for a generic approach, but I don't think that should matter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you dont specify how the relations look line - how EF may know it?

Comment: @Posio Like I said, EF adds a foreign key for the parent table to the child table, so obviously EF has figured the relation out correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'uh. It seems like I was looking at the wrong database the whole time...

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, aren't these two names suppose to match? Because everything seems correct, you should not need explicit insertion for the child entity EF should handle it.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo as I had censored the actual table names for the post. They do match.

Comment: Have you tried ForeignKey attribute? It should look like

[ForeignKey("MySharePointTable")]
public int OtherTableId { get; set; }

Comment: I don't want to add that because I drop and recreate the tables for every program run and that would make everything a lot more complicated (tables would have to be dropped in the right order). But I think that shouldn't matter? It could also be some other value instead of a foreign key? In fact, for some other tables, we store not a foreign key, but a BLOB, for example. EF shouldn't be concerned with that? The foreign key pointing to the parent table is generated correctly by EF.

Comment: And just to be clear "OtherTableId" points to a completely different table, not the parent (MySharePointTable).